# "TypeError: OAuth2.createService is not a function" when trying to use the OAuth2 library

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

I tried using the OAuth2 library - https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2

However, after I set up my variables I keep getting the createservice is not a function error. I get this for all of them methods from the library, as if its not activated. Any tips on what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

```
    function getToken() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.
  
      const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var client_id = scriptProperties.getProperty('CLIENT_ID');
  var secret = scriptProperties.getProperty('SECRET');
  
  
  var service = OAuth2.createService('Service')
  // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
  .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('X')
  .setTokenUrl('X')
  
  // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
  .setClientId(client_id)
  .setClientSecret(secret)
  
  // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
  // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
  .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
  
  // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
  
  // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
  .setScope('CustomerAPI.Public')
  
  .setParm()
  
  Logger.log(service);
  
}
```

Comment: Have you followed the instruction in the [`Setup`](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2#setup) section?

Comment: Yes, and I am using the latest version of the library

Comment: Not reproducible on my side, try to remove the library and add it again. `Logger.log(OAuth2.createService('drive'))`

Comment: Removed the library, saved. Re-added the library, saved.

As before, all the classes show up when I try 'OAuth2', ran the script and got the same error. :D

Comment: Probably unrelated typo: `setParm` should be `setParam()` with appropriate info. Could you remove all the script and start from scratch with only one function and one line  of code in that function `OAuth2.createService('Test')` in a brand new untouched project?

Comment: Just gave this a go, same error.

I don't understand, its as if the library doesn't exist at all but I tried adding it manually and as instructed in their setup guide

Comment: Do some debugging: `console.log(OAuth2);console.log(typeof OAuth2);for (let i in OAuth2){console.log(i)}`

Comment: Do you have any global variables(outside any function) named `OAuth2`? Could you try again [here](https://script.new)?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to resolve the issue by just starting from scratch

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted everything and re-pasted the dist from the GitHub repo then everything worked, seems like it was in conflict with the other library I posted or something